# newbie question on win32 app log

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, win32-process

I am new in in Visual Studio Win32 (C++) Applications
In java where I work, logging is easy using log4j for instance.
How is the logging done in a Win32 app?
I have seen some code using macros to write to files.
Am I responsible to create some logging mechanism?
Is there a standard way to log in win32?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the Event Log API to write to Windows Event Log
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385772(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is this approach better than writing to a file belonging to the application?I mean is it the common way in Win32 apps?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using log4net since you have experience of log4j, there are very similar.

Comment: I ask because I do not know this.It can be used by Win32 project app, right?

Answer (score 1):

"Windows application" doesn't mean much of anything, Java apps can also run on Windows.  There's log4net to adding logging to a .NET application.  Log4cxx to do so for an app written in C++.  Exact same approach as log4j.  The project's home page [is here](http://logging.apache.org/).

Comment: Right, I was right.  As posted, log4cxx helps you add logging to a C++ app.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who is going to be using your software's logging facility:

- The Windows Event Log API is best if you are writing a service or "system" type task that needs to be supported by an IT support department. Support tools for Windows support remote access of system event logs to create system health alerts and so on.

Other than that, Windows does not have a convenient Logging API. So you need to roll-your own if the system event log is inappropriate.

- For developers / debugging purposes theres OutputDebugString that will emit text to your debuggers "Output" window.
- It is convenient when writing GUI apps, to make the debug build a console application, so that a console window is displayed in addition to the GUI. printf() can display messages to the console.
- Otherwise, some OSS projects I built on windows did include a variant of log4c that had been ported to windows. So log4c can be coerced into working on windows if you really need it.

Comment: The application I need to write must do something specific in the background, and has minimum interaction
with the user through message boxes (e.g. the X app is installed do you want to proceed? etc).
So I do not have an actual GUI to display or a console to output.
The code I am currenty working on is using some macros to output info to a file.But the code is not suitable
because it is copy-paste from other app which already used it (i.e. it is tested).Problem is that it has a lot of 
stuff I do not need, and I do not like macros.
So is log4c as you mention, suitable for me?

Comment: wrt is Log4c suitable: That depends on the trace macro's being used. If theyre custom, you need to write your own wrappers anyway. If they are Log4x "compliant" then integrating log4c seems the way to go.